# adding a trailing comma to a print command makes threads executions "serialized"

Tags: python, multithreading

without dumping tones of code here is the symptom

having a threads which all run various methods of the same type of object.
within the methods i have a print line which reads:

`print self.args, self.foo`

everything works just fine.

However, if i turn that line into:

`# remain in the same line`

`print self.args, self.foo,`

execution is done in a serialize way and it seems like that print statement blocks other threads from being executed until it finishes.

```
import threading, time

class Graph2(object):
    def __init__(self, instanceName):
        self.instanceName = instanceName

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def foo():
            for i in xrange(10):
                #### the tricky line #### 
                # print i, self.instanceName
                print i, self.instanceName,
                time.sleep(1)

        return foo


class GraphThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, graph, method, *args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.g, self.m, self.args = graph, method, args
        self.results = None

    def run(self):
        print 'm=%s, args=%s' % (self.m, self.args)
        self.results = getattr(self.g, self.m)(*self.args)
        print "...done running method %s, with args %s:"%(self.m,self.args)

methods = ["degree","betweenness","closeness","cocitation","shell_index","evcent","eccentricity","constraint"]
threads=[]

# spawn a new thread for every requesting url
for method in methods:
    print "starting thread for method %s..."%method
    t=GraphThread(Graph2(method),method)
    t.start()
    print "..appending thread..."
    threads.append(t)
    print "...thread appendd."
```

Comment: Not what's commonly observed -- on the contrary an often heard complaint is that `print` statements from various threads get all mixed up.  What platform, OS and version, Python version, etc?

Comment: tzury@x200:~$ python --version
Python 2.6.5

tzury@x200:~$ uname -a
Linux x200 2.6.32-23-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 11 08:03:28 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flushing `stdout` after the print

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```